# How NodeJS modules (custom libs) works?

Tags: node.js, express, module

I want to build a custom authentication module (library) for NodeJS Express framework. This module will be open-sourced and will be uploaded on `npmjs.com`.

Basically, this module will have

1. Database connection (connection string fetched from the project which will use this module)
2. Few auth-related routes
3. Few auth-related middlewares

Here are my questions about this setup:

1. If I import `expressjs` dependency in this custom authentication module, and if this custom module is then used in another ExpressJS project, which might have a different version of `expressjs` dependency, then will it conflict or cause any issues?
2. Are the dependencies imported in this custom authentication module, will be limited for usage to only this module, or will be available in the parent project also which will use this module?

In short, I want to know how dependencies are migrated (managed) between parent project (main project) and the child modules (which are imported as a dependency in parent project)

Comment: It seems you are looking for https://nodejs.org/es/blog/npm/peer-dependencies

Comment: Not exactly. I want to develop a library for NodeJS which will have few features of ExpressJS, and thus I would need ExpressJS in that library. Question is, if I install different version of ExpressJS in my library, and if this library is added as a dependency in another NodeJS Express project, then will ExpressJS versions between library and the main project conflict?

Comment: Basically, I am talking about this - https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-node-js-modules. But my just question is around the dependencies which I will have in the module which I will develop, and the dependencies which will be there in parent project.